# Apache HTTPD URL based Strong Ciphers

Tags: apache, security, ssl, httpd.conf, http-proxy

**Question:**

I am researching a way to setup strong ciphers for a particular URL only in Apache HTTPD. The documentation shows that this functionality is supported and I am able to configure it. How do I test that it's in fact using strong ciphers just for the specific URL? All of the recommended tests I found are performed at the domain/server level. I tried ssllabs.com, command line nmap, openssl. I am fairly new to ciphers and setting up security in HTTPD. Are URL based Strong Ciphers not recommended/supported? Are there any tools out there that check at the URL level? Should I abandon the idea of a strong cipher per application and do it at the server level?

**Background:**

There are at least ten different applications behind Apache HTTPD. Moving to a strong cipher model for the entire server was considered high risk since various apps have a wide range of clients. We are researching a way to enable strong ciphers one app/URL at a time so that QA can test them one by one and to minimize the risk.

**Setup:**

```
OS: CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
HTTPD: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

The documentation related to Strong Ciphers for a specific URL is here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#strongurl

So far I've used the following tools to check ciphers

```
www.ssllabs.com/ssltest
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p port host
openssl s_client  -connect host:port
```

Here is what I have in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

```
<Location /myapp>
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
</Location>
```

I am using Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator to create a strong cipher model for our version of Apache. 
https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=apache&server-version=2.2.15&config=intermediate

Comment: `testssl.sh` (`https://testssl.sh/`) should be able to be run giving a specific URL... also your question would be more on topic for [su] or [sf]. Personnally I believe that `SSLCipherSuite` as many other related configuration should be per server, not per location/URL. Why would it make sense to require stronger/different crypto algorithms for `/foo` than for `/bar`? This seems very fragile as any kind of redirection, internal redirection, proxying, aliasing, etc. can go around such configuration...Use different hostnames for each of your applications? `app1.example.com`,`app2.example.com`...